# I am trying to do sorting local json file in React js but getting error: "TypeError: _Data_place_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not iterable."

Tags: json, reactjs, sorting

i am trying to do sorting local json file in React js but getting error:

> TypeError: _Data_place_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not iterable.

I am trying to sort my local data "title" alphabetical order. But I am getting error. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is my json file

```
{
    "users": [{
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
            "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 2,
            "title": "qui est esse",
            "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 3,
            "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
            "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
        },
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "id": 4,
            "title": "eum et est occaecati",
            "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my React child component where I am trying to sort.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import place from "./Data/place.json";

export class Restaurent extends Component {
  state = {
    place: place
  };

  sortName(search) {
    this.setState({
      place: [...place].sort((a, b) => a[search] < b[search])
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => this.sortName("name")}>sort</button>
        {place.users.map(name => {
          return <li>{name.title}</li>;
        })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Restaurent;
```

This is my app file

```
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";
import Restaurent from "./components/Restaurent";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Restaurent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Error is in this part: `[...place]`. `place` is an object and not iterable like that. `[...Object.keys(place)]` and `[...Object.entries(place)]` are valid but ``[...place]`` is not.

Comment: It does not show error but when I click the button it does not work either. It does not do sorting the title alphabetical order.

Comment: But you said in the question that it's giving an error: `TypeError: _Data_place_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not iterable.`. Now you're saying it doesn't give any error. I'm confused.

Comment: My goal is to sort "title" in alphabetical order when I will click the sort button. But it does not work. For example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow up from the comments section**

`places` is an object so you cannot use spread operator on it to copy into `array` like `[...places]` (`{...places}` is valid though). You need to write `[...places.users]` because `places.users` is an array and can be iterated for copying.

Also, you said you want to sort using `"title"` but you're passing `"name"` in

```
<button onClick={() => this.sortName("name")}>sort</button>
```

---

**Fix**: Do the following changes in your code

```js
sortName(search) {
    this.setState({
        place: [...place.users].sort((a, b) => {
            if(a[search] < b[search]) // Put a first
                return -1;
            if(a[search] > b[search]) // Put b first
                return 1;
            return 0;
        })
    });
}
```

**and**

```
<button onClick={() => this.sortName("title")}>sort</button>
```

---

### UPDATE

Actually there are lots of other errors in `Restaurent.js`. Here's a list of some:

1. `state` is not defined inside the constructor.
2. Inside `render()`, you're accessing `place` directly from the imported JSON file and not from the state and hence you won't see any change even after sorting.
3. You must pass a `key` prop to each child in `map()`.

Here's a correct and working(tested) `Restaurent.js` component:

```js
export class Restaurent extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            place: place
        };
    }
    sortName(search) {
        let sortedUsers = [...place.users].sort((a, b) => {
            if(a[search] < b[search]) // Put a first
                return -1;
            if(a[search] > b[search]) // Put b first
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });
        this.setState({
            place: {
                ...this.state.place,
                users: sortedUsers
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <button onClick={() => this.sortName("title")}>sort</button>
                {this.state.place.users.map((name,index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>{name.title}</li>;
                })}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: No man, just does not show any result. I did exactly what you said.

Comment: I want to do alphabetical order starts with "a" letter.